# ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" not in your path

Tags: android, cordova, path

I'm working on a Cordova app with my Mac and I have a problem with my `ANDROID_HOME` in my PATH.

I have set `ANDROID_HOME` into my PATH but when I reboot my Mac, it's not saved into it and I need to save it again.

Is there a solution to save the PATH after adding my variable ?

I use this command to save `ANDROId_HOME` in my path:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/sdk

export PATH = ${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I just can't change the path variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash:

`nano ~/.bashrc`

and put those lines there
`export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/sdk`
`export PATH = ${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

Usually they go to the bottom of that file.

If you're using zshell you can put it there too. Just `nano ~/.zshrc` and paste them.

When you reboot and open your terminal it will be there automatically. To verify you can:
`echo $ANDROID_HOME` or `echo $PATH`